# Twig: Determine whether a menu item has a translation

Tags: twig, drupal-8

In my Drupal 8 setup, I have two languages configured (German: default, English). Not all pages have a translation into English, but they show up in the navigation.

I'd like to highlight those menu items that link to pages that don't have a translation in the currently selected language.

So how can I do this in Twig? When I dump the menu item, I see an object of class *MenuLinkContent* that has a field *entity* which might contain the answer:

```
object(Drupal\menu_link_content\Plugin\Menu\MenuLinkContent)[31277]
    [...]
  protected 'entity' =>
    object(Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent)[31407]
      [...]
        protected 'translations' => 
          array (size=2)
            'x-default' => 
              array (size=2)
                ...
            'en' => 
              array (size=2)
                ...
[...]
```

But I don't seem to be able to actually read those values.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy, first, you have to add your current language to any variable by yourtheme_preprocess

```
yourtheme_preprocess(&$vars, $hook)
{
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $vars['langcode'] = $language;
}
```

and now in your twig template, you have to check your entity if has a translation,

```
{% if node.hasTranslation(langcode) %}
   {% set node = node.getTranslation(langcode) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This will definitely help if I'm already on the target page.
But I want to determine this from within the navigation. So what I need is a link from the navigation/menu item to the target node.